# How to use Dcmtk in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, dicom

I am working on a project where I have to read a dicom image.

I am unable to install dcmtk.  I am using win7 64-bit and vs2010.

Please explain the procedure to include dcmtk in my program.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To use the `Windows` + `DCMTK` + `QT`, you need to execute these follow steps:

- Compile the DCMTK (Step 1.A)
- Create your sample application (Step 2)
- Create your QT project file referring the compiled/installed DCMTK Libs (Step 3.B)
- Compile your application in your IDE (Step 4.B)

> If you are reading this and don't want to use the Qt, I am answering a version without Qt as well.
>
> Windows+VisualStudio+DCMTK: Steps `1.A`, `2`, `3.A` and `4.A`
>
> Linux+GCC+DCMTK: Steps `1.B`, `2`, `N/A`, `4.C`

---

### 1) Compile the DCMTK

First of all, to use the DCMTK library in your application, you should compile the DCMTK source code to generate the libraries:

While I am writing this, the last available version is 3.6.0. So, we should download it:

ftp://dicom.offis.de/pub/dicom/offis/software/dcmtk/dcmtk360/dcmtk-3.6.0.zip

After the download is finished, you need to unzip the folder. The DCMTK source doesn't have a project file, but it is not a problem, there is a CMakelist file responsible for generating a project file in your desirable Operational System/Compiler. If you are not familiar with CMake tool, you can read more here (https://cmake.org/)

#### 1.A) Compiling on Windows/Visual Studio 2012

1.A.1) You need to have an installed compiler, in my case, it was the Visual Studio 2012

1.A.2) Run the `CMake tool` to generate a project file to Visual Studio 2012. You need be able to fill the `source` DCMTK directory.

1.A.3) Now, execute the VisualStudio 2012, open the file `sln` created in the previous step (2) and compile the target `ALL_BUILD`

1.A.4) Re-Execute VisualStudio in `Admin` mode (because of permission `C:\Program Files`) to compile the target `INSTALL` (it will copy and install the DCMTK to default path: `C:/Program Files/DCMTK/`, we can reference it such **PATH_WHERE_DCMTK_WAS_INSTALLED**)

#### (1.B) Compiling on GNU/Linux GCC

I have tested at Ubuntu/CentOS. The first, you should go to `DCMTK Source` and run these following three commands:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=path_to_dcmtk
$ make all
$ sudo make install
```

example: path_to_dcmtk = /home/user/dcmtk

---

### 2) Creating your sample application

Create a file called `your_sample/testapp.cxx` with the following content. This a demonstration found in DCMTK Forum to open a DICOM file and print the patient's name.

```
#include "dcmtk/dcmdata/dctk.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   DcmFileFormat fileformat;
   OFCondition status = fileformat.loadFile("test.dcm");
   if (status.good())
   {
      OFString patientsName;
      if (fileformat.getDataset()->findAndGetOFString(DCM_PatientName, patientsName).good())
      {
         cout << "Patient's Name: " << patientsName << endl;
      }else{
         cerr << "Error: cannot access Patient's Name!" << endl;
      }

   }else{
      cerr << "Error: cannot read DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

---

### 3) Creating the Application Project using the VisuaStudio as Compiler

The created file at the previous step needs to be placed in a project. You can choose between the option `Windows VisualStudio (3.1)` and  `Windows Qt (3.2)`. If you are using Linux, you can skip this step.

#### 3.A) Windows with Visual Studio 2012 IDE

To create a Visual Studio project, you can use the `Wizard` and set the necessary settings such: `Linker`, `Libraries`, etc. However, to make easier on this answer, I will use the `CMakeList.txt` to create a Project for Visual Studio 2012. So, please, create a file called `your_sample/CmakeList.txt` with the following content:

```
PROJECT(testapp)

SET(DCMTK_DIR ABSOLUTE_PATH_WHERE_DCMTK_WAS_INSTALLED)
#an example: SET(DCMTK_DIR "C:\\Users\\test\\test_dcmtk\\DCMTK")

# settings for Microsoft Visual C++ 6
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "/nologo /W3 /GX /Gy /YX")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Z7 /Od")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/nologo /W3 /GX /Gy /YX")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd /Z7 /Od")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT /O2")

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_REENTRANT)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${DCMTK_DIR}/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${DCMTK_DIR}/lib)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(testapp testapp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testapp netapi32 wsock32 ofstd dcmdata)
```

#### 3.B) Windows QtCreator IDE using the VisuaStudio as Compiler

To create a project file for QtCreator IDE. You need to create a file called `your_sample/my_project.pro` with the following content:

```
SOURCES += testapp.cxx
CONFIG += debug console
DEFINES += _REENTRANT

QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -MD
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -MT
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG -= -MDd
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG = -MTd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -MD
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG -= -MDd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -MTd

INCLUDEPATH += (RELATIVE_PATH_WHERE_DCMTK_WAS_INSTALLED)/include
#an example: INCLUDEPATH += ../../../test_dcmtk/DCMTK/include

LIBS += -L"(RELATIVE_PATH_WHERE_YOU_INSTALLED_DCMTK)/lib" \
-ladvapi32 \
-ldcmdata \
-loflog \
-lofstd \
-lws2_32 \
-lnetapi32 \
-lwsock32
#an example: LIBS += -L"../../../test_dcmtk/DCMTK/lib" \
```

---

#### 4.A) Windows with Visual Studio 2012 IDE

Open the project file at `VisualStudio` and click on `Build`.

#### 4.B) Windows with QtCreator IDE using the VisuaStudio as Compiler

Open the project file at `QT` and click on `Build`.

#### 4.C) GNU/Linux - Command Line with GCC

```
g++ testapp.cxx -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/path_to_dcmtk/include -L/path_to_dcmtk/lib -pthread -ldcmdata -lz -loflog -lofstd -o main
```

---

> Please, note that whether you have compiled the libraries in `DEBUG` mode, your application should be compiled in `DEBUG` mode as well.

---

#### References

- How Install
  http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/file_install.html
- DCMTK Docs
  http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/
- FAQ #40: How do I use the DCMTK libraries in my own application? [MSVC]
  http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=652
- CMake Configuration
  http://support.dcmtk.org/wiki/dcmtk/howto/cmakeconfiguration360

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand how to use the code under Compiling your application + libDCMTK > Windows - Visual Studio. I only know modifying project properties. I just added the additional include directory and the additional library directories and get unresolved external symbol errors when I run testapp.cxx. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @Ruchir Sorry about the misunderstanding... You need to create a file called CMakeLists.txt. After that, you will create a `.sln` (Visual Studio Project file) file using the CMAKE.exe or CMake-GUI.

Comment: Step 3.A it seems that you have to add more libraries to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES, at least `oflog iphlpapi ws2_32`

Comment: @edtech what is your SO? Windows 10? Windows 8?

Comment: @well Windows Server 2008, but probably it's because I use Visual Studio 2015. I get linker errors without these libraries.

Comment: thanks @edtech, I will try to find a Windows Machine with VisualStudio 2015 and update the steps... thanks for let me know

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the instructions for the Dcmtk [installation](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/file_install.html). If you don't know how to include the library in your project, study the [qmake manual](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qmake-project-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Common Toolkit guys have addressed some of these issues. You could also use the Insight Toolkit

http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Main_Page

http://itk.org

In fact there is a bit of documentation on the ITK wiki, but ITK uses gdcm instead of dcmtk.

http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK_FAQ#How_to_read_a_volume_from_a_DICOM_series

Answer (score 1):

We have a project that is an implementation of DCMTk in Qt -- we call it QtDICOM, and it forms the foundation of many of our products (http://fluxinc.ca/medical)/.  Worth a look (https://bitbucket.org/fluxinc/qt-dicom).  We haven't documented the configuration particularly well, but you can probably figure it out if you have a look.

Note: It does depend on DCMTk being built and included in the various paths.