# How to build a DCMTK project file with CMake?

Tags: cmake, dcmtk

I am trying to build a DCMTK project file using the CMake gui, so I can use it in Qt. Unfortunately, I still get a few errors. I've read many related topics (e.g. [How to use Dcmtk in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052148/how-to-use-dcmtk-in-qt)), but I cannot find a solution to solve my errors:

[image]

**Output CMakeError.log:**

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified
```

**Output CMakeOutput.log:**

```
The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64
```

Comment: Maybe try a stable version of CMake first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a probem in the rc version of CMake. I installed the stable version like you told me and the problem disappeared. Thank you!